# Kineticjs: How to identify which group was dragged?

Tags: kineticjs

I'm working with Kineticjs.

I have some groups into a layer and they are draggable. When I drag a group, I would like to know which one has been dragged. Is there any way to know that?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, assuming you gave your group a name or some identifier, you could do:

```
group.on('dragend', function(){
    var name = this.getName(); //or any other variable of the group config, like x/y values
    alert(name);
});

group.on('dragend', function(){
    var id = this.getId(); //unique id
    alert(id);
});
```

if you don't give it an identifier you could do:

```
group.on('dragend', function(){
    var draggedGroup = this; // Identifies your group with 'this'
});
```

All in all, you have to attach an event to the group, like dragstart, dragmove, or dragend in order to identify if, as you need the function to return something.

Comment: if you wanted to identify just shapes, you should check this out, its much simpler: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-get-event-shape-with-kineticjs/

Comment: No, actually, I had already tried the last way that you propose in your last post but it doesn't work with groups. I wanted to identify groups and I finally got it with the way that you explain in your first answer. Thank you so much! It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I know its answered but its also possible to do it as shown below or mentioned in comments by @EliteOctagon.

```
layer.on('mousedown', function (evt) {

var SelectedGroup = evt.targetNode.getParent();

});
```

Source:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-get-event-shape-with-kineticjs/